# Portuguese citizenship using grandparents' birth certificates

Tags: citizenship, indian-citizens, portugal

I am an Indian citizen born in the 80's, ancestrally from Goa, India. Portuguese nationality law allows those who were Portuguese citizens connected with Portuguese India before 1961 to retain Portuguese nationality, up to 3 generations.

Both my parents were born in Goa in the 50's, and my grandparents were all born in Goa before 1920. I have managed to get provisional digital copies of their(6) birth certificates ("Registo de Nascimento") from a gov. website.

My spouse's parents were born outside Goa, but all her grandparents were born in Goa around the 1920's. I have not (yet) managed to get provisional digital copies of their(4) birth certificates.

My parents have Indian passports and other documents with anglicized names.

My queries are:

1. Is it true that I cannot prove that I am a descendant of my (grand)parents' since my parents have anglicised names, and that the only solution is for them to make new passports with their Portuguese names?
2. Since my spouse's parents were born outside Goa, would the overall process be easier for her, given the fact that her grandparents' docs are in Portuguese, her parents' docs are in English (and therefore no anglicization has taken place)?
3. Can I get Portuguese citizenship once my wife gets hers?